# RLMArray<> returns different instances each time

Tags: ios, realm

@Realm:

Why does my RLMArray gives different instances of objects at runtime?

This is how I defined my RLMArray:

```
@property RLMArray<HouseImage> *images;
```

I add/remove `HouseImage` objects to this array all the time (in transactions).

When I'm accessing the images as:

```
_house.images[indexPath.row]
```

every time I get different instances i.e.

```
(lldb) p _house
(RLMAccessor_v0_House *) $52 = 0x00000001701a5780
2015-08-30 23:02:07.695 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: 1C178A31-5F33-4CD3-9B7C-B026DF7A5E19_2
2015-08-30 23:02:07.731 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: CFD99689-12C4-49CB-AAB6-850FFCD902D7_3
2015-08-30 23:02:07.750 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: 194D55EA-125A-4CFC-8CCF-758E929BE7D5_4

// This is the first time when iterating the array. The [house] object remains same, but not the images array items.
(lldb) p _house
(RLMAccessor_v0_House *) $53 = 0x00000001701a5780
(lldb) p _house.images[0]
(RLMAccessor_v0_HouseImage *) $54 = 0x00000001740bbf60
2015-08-30 23:02:36.947 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: 1C178A31-5F33-4CD3-9B7C-B026DF7A5E19_2
2015-08-30 23:02:36.986 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: CFD99689-12C4-49CB-AAB6-850FFCD902D7_3
2015-08-30 23:02:37.031 Apt Note[5992:1308601] Loading image named: 194D55EA-125A-4CFC-8CCF-758E929BE7D5_4

// This is the second iteration
(lldb) p _house
(RLMAccessor_v0_House *) $55 = 0x00000001701a5780
(lldb) p _house.images[0]
(RLMAccessor_v0_HouseImage *) $56 = 0x00000001740bc140
```

If you see my log, the `house` object remains the same. However, the instances in the `RLMArray`(`images`) have changed out of nowhere. Nobody other than this piece of code are reading/writing to realm while this is happening.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

If I'm not clear, please let me know, I will try to explain even more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. In order to realize the zero-copy storage system, Realm does not hold the actual data at all. Realm swizzles the property accessors for your persisted properties to dynamically fetch the properties, so when you access the property multiple times, it actually returns a different instance each time, by design. `RLMArray` is also same　as it. So each time you want to access the elements of RLMArray, Realm returns by creating a different proxy object.

FYI: If the objects are not persisted, `RLMArray` returns same instances every time. Because the `RLMArray` is just backed by `NSArray` https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMArray.mm#L153-L159.

But once the object is persisted, `RLMArray` changes to `RLMArrayLinkView`. By the above reasons, `RLMArrayLinkView` will return  different instances every time. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMArrayLinkView.mm#L193-L197